# Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. - Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
    function pricing() {
      convert_txt_gsheets();
      lastrow2();
    }
    
    function convert_txt_gsheets() {
      var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
      var targetrange = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
      targetrange.clear();
    
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID2');
      var body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\r/);
      var result = body.map(split(/|/))
        // vvv
        .map(row => row.map(cell => cell.replaceAll(`"`, ``)));
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Report').getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
      return;
    }



function lastrow2() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Daily Report');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID1').getSheetByName('Permanent Record');
var target = target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow(), source.getLastColumn()).getValues();
target.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

Could I ask for help with the above code? The function Lastrows2 works properly. However, the Convert_txt_gsheets throws exception "Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 9. convert_txt_gsheets" which terminates the whole thing, and stops lastrow2 from ever engaging.

This is the example data that is being pulled from txt.

| COLUMN0 | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 | COLUMN5 | COLUMN6 | COLUMN7 | COLUMN8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Rocketship" | "5.99" | "5.39" | "5.39" | "" | "5.39" | "5.39" | "7.5.2022" | "william" |

Edit I modified the example and the original code. The error currently received is

> ReferenceError: split is not defined

Comment: Hi, there's some incorrect syntax in your code: `cell.replaceAll(", ``)`. Can you clarify what exact code you have? If I use `cell.replaceAll('"', "\`")` instead, I don't get any error (after grabbing the text you provided and upload to Drive a text file with that text), but I'm not sure what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @lamblichus My bad, I have copied over the old code. The issue you mention I have already resolved. I have edited the OP if you don't mind taking a look again.

To clarify the script is supposed to pull data from txt in the drive, put it in one of the sheets within the spreadsheet, and then copy the pulled data and add it to the second sheet. So it moves it to sheet 1, after first cleaning the sheet. and then copies it to sheet 2 adding it into the last row, creating an archive. The individual functions work somewhat okay. convert_txt_gsheets still runs into error however it works.

Comment: I can execute successfully, no errors, so I don't know what's going on here. My guess is that the text pulled from `txt` file is not exactly what you referenced. Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @lamblichus that was a great note, I realized that our data is slightly corrupted and makes use of commas. I change delimiter to "|"

`COLUMN0|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8
"Rocketship"|"5.99"|"5.39"|"5.39"|""|"5.39"|"5.39"|"7.5.2022"|"william"`

^New example.  I also updated the OP with new code and examples. However, now I receive the following "ReferenceError: split is not defined" Could you help me redefine it properly? Splits confuse me very much.

Comment: Change `var result = body.map(split(/|/))` to `var result = body.map(r => r.split(/|/))`. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: @lamblichus It has not sadly, now the following error is received: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 72 but the range has 79.

Comment: Same as before, this is not reproducible on my side, which most likely means the data you provided is not exactly the same as the one you're actually working on.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost good, the problem is here :

```
  var result = body.map(r => r.split(/,/))
    // vvv
    .map(row => row.map(cell => cell.replaceAll(", ``)));
```

Here the function I did and tested :

```
function cleantext() {

  var text = `COLUMN0,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5,COLUMN6,COLUMN7,COLUMN8
"Rocketship","5.99","5.39","5.39","","5.39","5.39","7.5.2022","william"
"WobblyHouse","3.99","3.49","3.49","","3.49","3.49","7.5.2022","billiam"`;

  var cleaned = text.split('\n').map(line => line.split(',').map(cell => cell.replace(/["]/g, "")));

  Logger.log(cleaned);
}

// [[COLUMN0, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7, COLUMN8], 
// [Rocketship, 5.99, 5.39, 5.39, , 5.39, 5.39, 7.5.2022, william], 
// [WobblyHouse, 3.99, 3.49, 3.49, , 3.49, 3.49, 7.5.2022, billiam]]
```

Comment: Sadly the issue happened to be something else. Could you take a look at the edited OP?

Comment: @Daniel Ask follow up questions  in a new question.  Don't change the question after a answer has been posted.